# Need Help Change Background Color on One Webpart

Tags: web-part, css

I have been struggling on changing the background color for one webpart. With the CSS below it does change the background color, blinks with the change for a quick sec, and then goes right back to the original color.

I do also want to mention I am using other CSS to change all colors, but this issue is just for the single.

```
<style>
    .ms-WPHeader TD[title^="Footer"] {
        background-color:yellow; 
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried using dev tools (F12 for Chrome/IE) to see what styles are affecting the web part? Also, have you tried `background-color:yellow !important;`?

Comment: Hi yes I have tried both of those and still no success

Comment: Where have you placed your web part? In some publishing page or some where else?